# How to remove *.dep files from project

Tags: netbeans

i created project from existing source in netbeans. I wonder if it is posible to exclude *.dep from files listed in project in netbeans?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify global settings like this:

1. Menu Tools -> Options
2. Click `Miscellaneous` Button at the top of dialog.
3. Select `Files` tab under the row of buttons.
4. Edit the field labeled Ignored Files Pattern add `|.*\.dep` before the last `$`

Java per project instructions (because I already wrote them):

1. Select the project in project pane on the left.
2. Right click for popup menu.
3. Select `Properties` near the bottom of the menu.
4. Select `Sources` in the categories list on the left of dialog.
5. Click the `Includes/Excludes`  button near the bottom-right of dialog.
6. Enter `*.dep` in the Excludes field.

Comment: I don't have sources category in categories

Comment: What kind of project is it?

Comment: c/c++ project with existing sources  i have netbeans version 8.0.2

Comment: The previous instructions work for Java projects, but there is also a global setting that should work for a C++ project.